# Folders in nuxt render on two URLs

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm using dynamic folders in the style of

```
_category/index.vue
_category/_post.vue
```

so example.com/examplecategory renders the category overview page and example.com/examplecategory/posttitle renders the post. This works well.

Unfortunately example.com/examplecategy/ (note the trailing slash) renders the same content as the url without the slash at the end.

There's two problems with that:

- It's two URLs with the same content (nothing you want to have SEO wise)
- the @nuxt/google-analytics plugin seems like it can't deal with it. It even doesn't recognize the version without the slash correctly (reports / to  analytics instead of /examplecategory as URL)

Is there any easy way to redirect one version to the other? For the GA module it looks like the version with the slash would be the one to go even thought I would prefer to have no trailing slashes at all and I think this is generally the prefered way.

Any help on that end is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nuxt-trailing-slash](https://github.com/WilliamDASILVA/nuxt-trailingslash-module) module

or you can do a redirect the server that you are using like nginx or whatever